# sending sessions with variables from page to page through a form

Tags: php, session

hello i have a form and this form when i submit it, it goes to another page but my problem is that its don't work when i try to read the session values on the other page it doesn't work i really don't know what is the problem.

my first page which has the my form

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<strong>Test Form</strong>
<form action="payment.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="yourName"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>




<?php

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
  $yourName = $_POST['yourName'];


  if (isset($yourName) && !empty($yourName)) {
    $_SESSION['yourName'] = $yourName;
  }



  if(isset($yourName) && !empty($yourName)) {
    header('Location:payment.php');
  }
}
?>
```

My second page where i receive i want to present my values

```
<?php
session_start();

?>

<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['yourName'])){
echo "<div>";
echo htmlentities($_SESSION['yourName']);

echo "</div>";
}else{
    echo "fail";
}


// Finally, destroy the session.
?>

<?php session_destroy();
 ?>
```

Comment: Keep action tag blank if post to the same page, action=""

Comment: why not just post to page 2 i see no reason to use sessions here at all

Comment: Also check session id before session start.

Comment: Thank's Dagon i'm using here sessions because after that i will use this data to store in the database and i will use it to integrate in a payment gateway  LearningMode Thank you but i already checking it what else i should do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your code flowing way. These should not be `action` because of you submit form into same page and then redirect other page.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<strong>Test Form</strong>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="yourName"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
  $yourName = $_POST['yourName'];
  if (isset($yourName) && !empty($yourName)) {
    $_SESSION['yourName'] = $yourName;
    header('Location:payment.php');
  } 
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

OK so i was missing somethings and i found the solution
FIRST: When yous send data from page to page the action should be blank `action=""`
Then my second mistake was that i didn't check well my input names in the sessions after i checked i found that i had a difference so i made them the same.
Thank's

the working one is like : FIRST PAGE

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<strong>Test Form</strong>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="yourName"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>




<?php

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
  $yourName = $_POST['yourName'];


  if (isset($yourName) && !empty($yourName)) {
    $_SESSION['yourName'] = $yourName;
  }



  if(isset($yourName) && !empty($yourName)) {
    header('Location:payment.php');
  }
}
?>
```

SECOND PAGE is :

```
<?php
session_start();

?>

<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['yourName'])){
echo "<div>";
echo htmlentities($_SESSION['yourName']);

echo "</div>";
}else{
    echo "fail";
}


// Finally, destroy the session.
?>

<?php session_destroy();
 ?>
```